# Do Shi'a Muslims practice circumcision in adherance to the Covenant of Abraham?

Tags: shiism, prophet-ibrahim, covenant, khitan

Biblically, circumcision is a sign of the [Abrahamic Covenant](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+17&version=KJV) between God and Abraham, and was incumbent on him and each of his (male) descendents lest they be "[cut off from his people.](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2017:14&version=KJV)"

Insofar as they're descended from Ishmael, one could argue that Arabs (especially the prophet himself and his descendants) would be accounted as among Abraham's offspring and thus still affected by the Covenant.  However, it would be harder to extend this same to non-Arab muslims who are not descended from the Abrahamic line (either by blood or by adoption).

To my understanding, circumcision is also considered mandatory in Shi'a Islam:  Is there any evidence that this is directly due to the Covenant of Abraham, and if so, does it (the Covenant) apply to even those Muslims not of Abrahamic descent?

Answer (score 2):

No, they practice it based on order of Islam. Ahl ul Bayt in different Hadith said it is obligatory.

In Shia Islam it is not necessary to follow religion of prophet Ibrahim (a.s.) because it is partially different of Islam. For example the prayer in religion of prophet Ibrahim (a.s.) is different of prayer in Islam. Shia Islam gets rules only from Quran, Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) and infallible Ahl ul al Bayt (a.s.)

**Reference:**

- [porseman.org](http://porseman.org/q/show.aspx?id=136080)